# Which is the best way on AWS to set up a CI/CD of a Django app from GitHub?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a Django Web Application which is not too large and uses the default database that comes with Django. It doesn't have a large volume of requests either. Just may not be more than 100 requests per second.
I wanted to figure out a method of continuous deployment on AWS from my source code residing in GitHub. I don't want to use EBCLI to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk coz it needs commands in the command line and is not automated deployment. I had tried setting up workflows for my app in GitHub Actions and had set up a web server environment in EB too. But it ddn't seem to work. Also, I couldn't figure out the final url to see my app from that EB environment. I am working on a Windows machine.

Please suggest the least expensive way of doing this or share any videos/ articles you may hae which will get me to my app being finally visible on the browser after deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/en/codepipeline/), a service that builds, tests, and deploys your code every time there is a code change, based on the release process models you define. Use CodePipeline to orchestrate each step in your release process. As part of your setup, you will plug other AWS services into CodePipeline to complete your software delivery pipeline.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/cicd_for_5g_networks_on_aws/cicd-on-aws.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for advice! I will try what you said.